# Bootstrap 3 Landscape View on High Density Mobile

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've just designed my first Bootstrap site using version 3.  Prior to this, I have been using the Responsive Grid system.  When I go to view it in landscape on an iPhone 5 or LG G2, the pixel density causes the page to be displayed in the small portrait view.

I spent yesterday reading up on media queries but I'm a bit of a novice.  Let's say that I use one of the queries for the iPhone 5 specifically.  In the CSS portion, what default classes need to be modified so that the page remains wide while in landscape?

The Responsive Grid system didn't use pixels in the CSS and from what I can remember, I didn't have this problem.  Do I need to overhaul the Bootstrap CSS to fix the problem?

Comment: Media queries are related to pixel width.  You should find out how wide iPhone 5 landscape is and adjust accordingly.  Media queries are in your CSS file and start with @media.  I don't think anyone is going to list out the classes, but you could find them by reviewing bootstrap docs and/or your CSS files.

Comment: I understand the media queries.  The iPhone specifically uses the widest (568px) as the height even when it is in landscape mode.  So I guess I would be fighting two problems.  Does every single query that is @media (max-width:768px) need to be modified so the it understands the device pixels?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the viewport scale.
E.g.
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

[More info here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-mobile)

Comment: Are you looking for a media query to target high pixel density devices then?

Comment: I'm not specifically looking to target these devices.  Most of the posts are specific about doing just that.  I would like the page to stay wide in landscape mode, just as a device with a pixel ratio of 1 would do.

Comment: Could you add a jsfiddle or codepen to illustrate what you want?

Comment: I'm not looking to do anything special.  If you go to the Bootstap v3 official site on an iPhone 5, LG G2, or Samsung S4 in landscape, the page is in a <768px view.  My Galaxy Nexus that is older and has lower resolution displays the page properly in landscape.  Its just phones with pixel ratios >1 that display like a low resolution screen.